# How to work around Go array sizes in functions

Tags: arrays, go

I just started using Go, and one thing that makes me nervous is that if I define a function that accepts an array, and then pass an array to a function with a specific size, VS Code complains about it.

For example, I have something like this:

```
func cmplt(a, b []uint64) uint64 {
    var r, m, i uint64
    r = 0
    m = 0

    for i = 2; i >= 0; i-- {
        r |= LtUint64(a[i], b[i]) & ^m
        m |= MaskUint64(NeUint64(a[i], b[i]))
    }

    return r & 1
}
```

And then I call this function inside another function as:

```
func singleSample(in []uint64) uint64 {
    var i, index uint64
    index = 0

    for i = 0; i < 52; i++ {
        index = SelectUint64(index, i+1, cmplt(in, table[i]))
    }

    return index
}
```

where `table` has type `[52][3]uint64`. I get an error message saying: `cannot use table (type [3]uint64) as []uint64 in argument to cmplt`.

Is there any way in Go to workaround this, instead of specifically specifying the array size in function parameter?

Comment: You are confusing arrays and slices, which are two different kinds of types in Go. I would suggest first reading the following Go blog post on the subject: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @TimCooper Yes, I read a bit. And I see they mean different things in Go. But, still I don't know how can I make Go not complain for something like I have above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cmplt` is expecting a `uint64` slice, and not a 3 element array. [Taking a slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) of `table[i]` will fix the error:

```
cmplt(in, table[i][:])
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the best solution is to change your `cmplt` function definition to accept arrays:

`func cmplt(a, b [3]uint64) uint64 {`

In your code you any way rely on the size of the underlying array, hence make sure to specify your function dependencies as clear as possible